# System account login Cefsharp program crashes

Tags: windows, .net-5, cefsharp.offscreen

We deployed a windows service in which `cefsharp` is used. Logging in with the system account for the service will crash, but there is no problem with the Administrator account.

The following is cefsharp debug log:

> [0503/180128.058:ERROR:crashpad_client_win.cc(534)] CreateProcess:
> 系统找不到指定的文件。 (0x2) [0503/180128.074:INFO:crash_reporting.cc(216)] Crash
> reporting enabled for process: browser
> [0503/180128.074:ERROR:message_window.cc(118)] Failed to create a
> message-only window: 内存资源不足，无法处理此命令。 (0x8)
> [0503/180128.074:FATAL:window_impl.cc(149)] Check failed: . : 操作成功完成。
> (0x0) [0503/180128.074:ERROR:crashpad_client_win.cc(142)] crash server
> failed to launch, self-terminating

The CefSharp Version is CefSharp.OffScreen.NetCore 110.0.250.
The environment is `.NET5` and WindowsServer2016.

Now I use Administrator account login service circumvents this problem